# Does iOS Smart App Banner work in iOS Chrome/Firefox browsers?

Tags: ios, smart-app-banner

Does Smart App banner work in any other browser in iOS device other than Safari Mobile browser ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because the smart banner is not included in your website, it is in safari browser, you just point it by adding a meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a method similar to this:
https://github.com/dhsiao/smarter-app-banner

Where you use javascript to search for the meta tag and then create your own Smart App Banner.